# Google Navigator like Auto Complete inputs for an Android app

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm creating an android application where I can input the starting point and the destination, and based on those locations (Longitude and Latitiude) I will update the resulting UI with relevant details.

I need these two input items to behave like the google maps navigator, where the locations are suggested while the user is typing them. I used the Place Auto Complete widget, but it's giving me the "Powered by Google" notification, which I do not want. I also need to have the feature to get the current location from GPS as the starting point. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Re the "Powered by Google" logo. Note that displaying this logo is a requirement of using the API (see [Logo Requirements](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#logo_requirements))

For finding the users current location, you probably want to call [`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: But I've seen places that you don't have the powered by google logo. Is there any custom implementation around this?